# Adjust Matlab Gui parameter while playing an audio

Tags: matlab, audio

I would like to design a very simple MATLAB Gui program to adjust the magnitude of an audio while it is being played via a slider (`slider1`). However, the program any adjustment will not response until the audio is finished playing. How could I fix this?

The audio is played after a push button is pressed

[image]

```
function PlayFile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%Reading the audio file
FrameSize = 2048;
AR = dsp.AudioFileReader('Filename','test.wav','SamplesPerFrame',FrameSize);
Fs = AR.SampleRate;
%initializing audio player
AP = dsp.AudioPlayer('SampleRate',Fs);
tic
Tstop = 30;    %playing time


 while toc < Tstop
    gain = get(handles.slider1,'value');  %Get the gain factor
    audioIn = step(AR);
    audioOut = audioIn*gain;
    step(AP,audioOut);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the simplest, very old, matlab function to play wave PCM audio is "sound(x,Fs,Nbits)" and it is a high level function that will buffer the entire piece before it is played. And it will not allow adjustment on "x" before it is fully played. If your play function is also similar in mechanism, then you shall consider either using a low level audio playback function or divide your audio into small pieces and send each piece in sequence. However this last method may create problems due to multimedia timing issues. And as a result played audio may have pops & cracks in it.